# Show that none of the Du Val singularities of type $A$ is also of type $D$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the non-exceptional Du Val singularities:

$$
A_n : x^2 + y^2 + z^{n+1} = 0, \qquad \qquad
D_n : x^2 + y^2 z + z^{n-1} = 0
$$

I want to show that none of the $A_n$ singularities is isomorphic to a $D_n$ one.

I have already constructed their respective fields of fractions:

- For $A_n$, notice that $x - iy \in \mathbb C(x + iy, z)$. Therefore,

  $$\mathbb C(A_n) = \mathbb C(x,y,z) = \mathbb C(x + iy, x - iy, z) = \mathbb C(x + iy, z)$$
- For $D_n$, set $u = x/z^k$ and $v = y/z^k$, where $k$ is the greatest integer such that $2k < n$. Substituting in the equation of $D_n$, we reduce to one of the following cases:

  $$u^2 + v^2 z + z = 0, \qquad \text{or} \qquad u^2 + v^2 z + 1 = 0$$

  In either case, we have $z \in \mathbb C(u,v)$. Therefore,

  $$\mathbb C(D_n) = \mathbb C(x,y,z) = \mathbb C(u,v,z) = \mathbb C(u,v)$$

Now observe that:

- The transcendental generators I chose of $\mathbb C(A_n)$ are both already in the the coordinate ring $\mathbb C[A_n]$. In other words, $\mathbb C[A_n]$ contains a free $\mathbb C$-subalgebra whose field of fractions is the whole of $\mathbb C(A_n)$.
- The transcendental generators I chose for $\mathbb C(D_n)$ are neither in the coordinate ring $\mathbb C[D_n]$. I conjecture that $\mathbb C[D_n]$ indeed contains no free $\mathbb C$-subalgebra whose field of fractions is the whole of $\mathbb C(D_n)$.

Is my conjecture true? If so, how could I prove it? Please only give me the smallest hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Milnor rings of these singularities:
$$
\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x,y,z^n) \cong \mathbb{C}[z]/z^n
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x,yz,y^2 + (n-1)z^{n-2})
$$
are not isomorphic (the tangent space at the origin of the first is 1-dimensional and of the second is 2-dimensional), hence the singularities are not isomorphic as well.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, how is the Milnor ring of a singularity defined? EDIT: Never mind, I found the definition here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/156527/1871

Comment: On a second thought, I still need help. How would I show that the Milnor ring is a geometric invariant of the singularity? In principle, if I use a different embedding of either surface in affine space, then maybe I could obtain a non-isomorphic Milnor ring. How do I know that this cannot happen?

Comment: It can be reconstructed as $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\Omega_X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, so it definitely is independent on the embedding.

Comment: Nice, and thank you very much!